# Noise from bathroom fan when fan is off

Tags: hvac, bathroom

Bathroom fan/light recently started making a humming noise even when the unit is off. Any ideas what I could be? Just started after three years of use.

[Video of noise. Fan itself is unplugged but light is plugged in for visibility. Noise is still present with both unplugged.](https://file.io/WAnHjmQz4OYu)

Comment: Turn off the circuit breaker for this circuit and see if the noise goes away, or remains.